# 400 Bad Request Error with Parse Push Rest API on JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push-notification, ionic-framework

I'm encountering a problem with my Ionic application.  I am trying to make use of the Rest API for send push notifications with Parse.  I can use their push console to successfully send notifications.

However the following function throws error code 115 and a message saying "error: "Missing the push data." Please let me know if you need any other information for the issue.
Thank you.

```
$scope.send = function()


{
    $http({
      url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        "alert": "Alert Message", //not platform specific
        "badge": "1", //platform specific iOS
        "sound": "", //platform specific iOS
        "channels":["test"] 
      },
      headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": "removed",
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "removed",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log("Push sent!");
                  //alert('iOS registered success = ' + data + ' Status ' + status); 
          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(config)
    });

  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution. The following works with the REST API:

```
$scope.send = function()


{
    $http({
      "url": "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
      "method": "POST",
      "data": {
          "data": { "alert": "Alert Message", "sound": "", "badge": "Increment" },"channel":""
         // this line needed correct JSON formatting
      },
      "headers": {
          "X-Parse-Application-Id": "removed",
          "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "removed",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log("Push sent!");
                  //alert('iOS registered success = ' + data + ' Status ' + status); 
          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(config)
    });

  };
```

I didn't have the correct JSON key-value formatting.  Hope this helps others when using Angular to make HTTP POST requests using the Parse REST API.